# Inline <li> nav, reveal submenu elements by sliding in from left

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a menu built with `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>Item 1</li>

  <ul class="expand">
    <li>item 2</li>

    <ul class="sub"> 
      <li>sub 1</li>
      <li>sub2</li>
    </ul>

  </ul>

  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

My CSS puts all the `<li>` elements in a row.  When the user hovers over `item 2`, I would like the `sub` element to appear in the same row by sliding in from the left.  When the `sub` element slides in, I would like it to push `item 3` to the left as well.

Here is an example I set up, without transitions:

http://codepen.io/ben393/pen/mWdLEV

How can I create this effect, preferably using only CSS?

Comment: As per current [`HTML4 Standard`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-ul-element) the only valid `HTML` content allowed in `<ul>`s are *zero or more `<li>` or `<script>`* tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using CSS transitions to increase the width of a wrapper.  The submenu is floated to the right of the wrapper, causing it to appear to be pulled from the left.  I also switched my HTML from a list to divs to make it compliant with HTML standard.

```css
.nav div,
.nav span{
  display:inline-block;
}
.nav span{
  padding-right:15px;
}
.subwrap{
  width:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:right;
  transition: 1s;
}
.expand:hover .subwrap{
  height:auto;
}
.expand:hover .subwrap,
.sub{
  width:118px;/*must be wide enough to contain menu items*/
}
.sub{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <!-- our menu -->
  <span>Item 1</span>
  <!--menu items contained in spans-->

  <div class="expand">
    <!-- container for expanding submenu, will stretch-->
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <!--main menu item always visible-->

    <div class="subwrap">
      <!--expands to fit sub when we hover on expand element -->
      <div class="sub">
        <!--remains a constant width, floated to right of subwrap-->
        <span>Sub 1</span>
        <span>Sub2</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <span>Item 3</span>
  </ul>
```